# Remove old records in mongodb based on Month

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to  delete Older records present in my collection .

I have a collection named "user_track" , which consists of data in this format shown below

```
db.user_track.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("50c9afe5765fb0e4fea076ce"),
        "cust_id" : "ddddd",
        "symbol" : "WWWW",
        "access_time" : "Thu Dec 13 2012 05:37:25 GMT-0500 (EST)"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("50c9afe7765fb0e4ffa076ce"),
        "cust_id" : "eeeeeeeeee",
        "symbol" : "WFC",
        "access_time" : "Thu Dec 13 2012 05:37:27 GMT-0500 (EST)"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("522de3ae2191b0e41a7534dd"),
        "cust_id" : "dsdsds",
        "symbol" : "APPLE",
        "access_time" : "Mon Sep 09 2013 11:05:18 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
}
```

In my collection , user_track , i want to keep only the current month's data (that is from Sep 01 2013 to current day ) and want to delete the rest of the records which doesn't belong to current month

I have tried to issue the below command , but i am not sure of how to issue this command to suit my requirement as the date i have is in different format .

```
db.user_track.delete( { 'access_time': {$lte: XXX} })
```

Please suggest .

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can give any Date with Javascript date

```
db.user_track.remove( { access_time : {"$lt" : new Date(year, month_0_indexed, day)} })
```

So for removing documents before 1 September 2013 your command should be

```
db.user_track.remove( { access_time : {"$lt" : new Date(2013, 8, 1) } })
```

September is the 9th month but the month field is zero indexed. So we make that as 8.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `month_0_indexed`. :p

Answer (score 11):

Mongo has a TTL feature on collections, I think this is a nice solution to such cases:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Basically something like:

> db.log_events.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds:
>   3600 } )

Comment: You didn't know whose life you've saved dude, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Probably there is a cleaner solution but this should work:

1. Create new Data field from date strings:

   ```
   var cursor = db.user_track.find()
   while (cursor.hasNext()) {
       var doc = cursor.next();
       db.user_track.update(
           {_id : doc._id},
           {$set : {access_time_ : new    Date(doc.access_time)}})
   }
   ```
2. Now you can retrieve some records by comparing dates:

   ```
   db.user_track.find({access_time_: {$lt: new Date("Sep 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+00:00")}})
   ```
3. If everything works as expected remove obsolete records:

   ```
   db.user_track.remove({access_time_: {$lt: new Date("Sep 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+00:00")}})
   ```
4. In the future use date objects not strings

Comment: Thanks for the update , you mean do i need to exeute remove manually for each date ??

Comment: I am not if I understand you correctly. {access_time_: {$lt: new Date('Sep 1, 2013')} should match all docs with access_time_ before 'Sep 1, 2013'. So as long you don't call remove with justOne set to True it will remove all documents matched by query.

Comment: @zero323 The date you give in single quotes in **not** in UTC. It is system dependent.

Comment: @bsd Thank for noticing. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to other answers you may be interesting in the "Time to live” collection feature:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

It's useful to automatically expire/remove documents from a collection after specific period of time.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to address this issue .

```
var date=new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
db.user_track.remove({"access_time":{"$lt":date}});
```

I will make this run automatically by putting these lines in a bash file and scheduling that script using a cron tab .

Please share your views if this is a valid solution or not ??

Comment: `getDate` returns the day of the month. is that what you were looking for ? See my solution.

Comment: @bsd i have tried this in my development environment and its working fine .

Comment: Maybe it works because you don't have dates from previous month. Try inserting a few more dates. I don't think this works. It just deletes documents from yesterday onwards. You can check in mongo shell by typing the variable `date` again.