# How to delete mongodb data which is less than a certain date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have inserted few documents as

```
db.employees.insert({"_id": 7, "firstName": "neh","joining_date": "2017 03 24"})
db.employees.insert({"_id": 8, "firstName": "neh","joining_date": "2017 03 23"})
db.employees.insert({"_id": 9, "firstName": "neh","joining_date": "2017 03 22"})
db.employees.insert({"_id": 10, "firstName": "neh","joining_date": "2017 03 21"})
```

db.employees.find() show me:-

```
{ "_id" : 7, "firstName" : "neh", "joining_date" : "2017 03 24" }
{ "_id" : 8, "firstName" : "neh", "joining_date" : "2017 03 23" }
{ "_id" : 9, "firstName" : "neh", "joining_date" : "2017 03 22" }
{ "_id" : 10, "firstName" : "neh", "joining_date" : "2017 03 21" }
```

I wanted to delete documents less than date 2017 03 24. So I tried:

```
db.employees.remove( { joining_date : {$lt : new Date(2017, 3, 24) } });
```

it showed:-
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 0 })
Then tired:-

```
db.employees.remove( { joining_date : {$lt : new Date(2017, 2, 24) } });
```

Still it showed:-
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 0 })

Also tried:-

```
db.employees.remove( { joining_date : {$eq : new Date(2017, 3, 24) } });
db.employees.remove( { joining_date : {$eq : new Date(2017, 2, 24) } });  
db.employees.remove( { joining_date : {"$lt" : new Date(2017, 3, 24) } });
db.employees.remove( { joining_date : {"$lt" : new Date(2017, 2, 24) } });
```

All gives me:-
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 0 })

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716461/remove-old-records-in-mongodb-based-on-month/18718789)  But it doesn't work for me. What am I missing?

Comment: `"joining_date": "2017 03 24"` is not in date format, it is in string format.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the following two ways to delete documents from the collection, for a given "date" condition. The date comparison can be done either with the string date (it is possible in this case as date string is in "YYYY mm dd" format) *or* using a date object (this requires conversion of the string date to `date` object using the aggregation operator `$dateFromString`).

```
db.test.remove( { joining_date: { $gt: "2017 03 22"} } )

db.test.remove( { $expr: { $gt: [ { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$joining_date", format: "%Y %m %d" } }, ISODate("2017-03-22") ] } } )
```

Note the `$dateFromString` aggregation operator could be used in this query with the help of the `$expr` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You compare a **string** (`"2017 03 24"`) with a **Date** (`new Date(2017, 3, 24)`), this does not work.

Save `joining_date` as proper `Date` objects (the preferred way of doing it) or compare with string, e.g. `{$eq: "2017 03 24"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
db.employees.aggregate( [ {
   $project: {
      date: {
         $dateFromString: {
            dateString: '$joining_date',
                  format: "%Y %m %d",
            timezone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
         }
      }
   }
} ] ).forEach(function (doc){
    var query_date = new Date(2017, 2, 24)
    if(doc.date  < query_date){
              db.employees.remove({"_id": doc._id});
    }
});
```

This should work.

`new Date()` -> Month variable starts from 0(for January)